# How to authenticate user with Amazon PHP SDK of Amazon Congnito

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I use **ConfirmSignUp** method to confirm user, after that, how can I authenticate a user with its email and password ?

```
$identityProvider = AWS::createClient('CognitoIdentityProvider');

$result = $identityProvider->confirmSignUp([
    'ClientId'         => 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
    'ConfirmationCode' => $code,
    'Username'         => $username
]);
```

I found the method **InitiateAuth**, but it does not appear to be.

With the JS SDK example ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html ), JS can authenticate user with following code:

```
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },
});
```

I use Amazon PHP SDK ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentity.CognitoIdentityClient.html ).

Does PHP SDK have the same method ? or where I can find some document about it ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Cognito doesn't support high level SDK for PHP. The low level SDK can be used by calling the APIs mentioned below,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentityProvider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient.html

Instead of calling InitiateAuth, you may want to call AdminInitiate auth API with ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH parameter, so that you don't need to do SRP computation in PHP. User pools uses SRP to verify passwords, the math for which is quite complex. The mobile SDKs handle it for you, but using admin no srp auth bypasses that.